# Signalr application deployment failed on remote server

Tags: c#, javascript, deployment, signalr

Working on an application with the signalr. Locally, everything works fine but when deploying on a server appear problems.

When i try to resolve in the `application_start()` my hub:

```
 IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ImageHub>();
```

I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'ImageHub' Hub could not be
>   resolved. --at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubManagerExtensions.EnsureHub(IHubManager
>   hubManager, String hubName, IPerformanceCounter[] counters) --at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext(String
>   hubName)

Accordingly in signalr/hubs in js i have no the following 3 lines:

```
proxies.imageHub = this.createHubProxy('imageHub');
proxies.imageHub.client = { };
proxies.imageHub.server = {
    sendImages: function (filterModel, ids) {
        return proxies.imageHub.invoke.apply(proxies.imageHub, $.merge(["SendImages"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
    }
};
```

Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
 {

     DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(DataFormatAttribute), typeof(DataFormatValidator));
      IContainer container = new InjectionConfigurationWeb().Container;
      DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
      GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new Autofac.Integration.SignalR.AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
      RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
      AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

 ...

}
```

Server iis 7.5 on both boxes.

Bin folder contains the same dlls on both servers.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your code is calling MapHubs() before you call GetHubContext<T>()?

Comment: Yes. Solution is absence of several dlls on server box: Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll and Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll. After installing ReportViewer it works fine on production computer. By the way i don't know how signalr depends on Reportviewer but it fixed my issue.